# How can I prove that the solutions of this differential equation is monotone?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to proof if $x:I\to \mathbb R$ a maximal regular solution of $x'=f(x)$, such that the image $x(I)\subset \mathbb R$ is bounded and $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$, then $x$ is strictly monotone. How can I prove that $f$ doesn't change sign?

I need help

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need to prove that "$f$ does not change sign"?

Comment: I might be saying something stupid but if $f\equiv 0$ (constant function, zero), then any solution $x$ is constant too, not strictly monotone.

Comment: @Artem because the derivative of $x$ is strictly positive or negative, then $x$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: OK, and what happens when $f(x)=0$?

Comment: I would echo @ClementC.'s comment...

Comment: @copper.hat There is word "regular" solution, which seems to mean that the case $f\equiv 0$ is excluded.

Comment: @Artem: Thanks. Never heard of it before in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(r) = 0$, $x=r$ is a constant solution of $x' = f(x)$, and it certainly isn't strictly monotone.  Moreover, by the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem every solution on an interval $I$ that takes the value $r$ at some point of $I$ is constant.  On the other hand, if $x: I \to \mathbb R$ is a solution and $f \ne 0$ at all points of the interval $x(I)$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem either $f > 0$ on $x(I)$ or $f < 0$ on $x(I)$.  In the first case, 
$x' > 0$ so $x$ is strictly increasing; in the second case $x' < 0$ so $x$ is strictly decreasing.